# Link in sign up hung

Tags: bug, android-app, sign-up

I have Google account connected already. But when I go with sign-up and click on Google sign-in, it hangs.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: Sony
- Device Model: E2363
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (4059386522)

Comment: There is new version 1.0.93. Try to update.